# PowerShell to generate Mailbox Report

Tags: powershell, exchange-server, powershell-3.0, office365

Is it possible to use PowerShell to generate reports from Office365 for a single mailbox? I've searched Micorosft, and see there are a number of report cmdlets, such as Get-MailboxStatistics, Get-MailTrafficSummaryReport etc, but nothing which can generate a report showing what I'd like, which is a report of all mail that has come into a single mailbox, showing the sender, the subject & date/time. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Get-MessageTrace](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj200704%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx) for that.  It will return [MessageTrace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.management.fforeporting.messagetrace_members(v=exchg.150).aspx) objects that will have the sender, subject and timestamp information you need for your report.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've tried `Get-MessageTrace -RecipientAddress user@domain.com -StartDate 01/05/2015 -EndDate 24/03/2015` but I get an error saying: _Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'EndDatet'. Cannot convert value "24/03/2015" to type "System.DateTime"._. `Get-Culture` confirms I am using en-GB UK English, so the date/time format are correct as dd/mm/yyyy. StartDate is accepted, but not endDate

Comment: I don't think those parameters are localized.  Use 'MM/dd/yyyy' format date strings. If it was using dd/mm/yyyy format it should complain about that start date, which is invalid because it would be in  the future.

Comment: OK, think I've fixed the EndDate, as you say, it's in US format. When I did the same with StartDate I got an error telling me it could be mor ethan 30 days before todays date. So looks like I can only pull a report for the last 30 days. I was hoping to do a year to date report.

Comment: There's not much you can do about that. You can do a mailbox search, but that's only going to show you what's still in the mailbox, not what was actually received.